# CSS for table headers in computer-database-jpa sample?

Tags: css, playframework-2.0, styles, css-shapes

In Play 2, there's a sample `computer-database-jpa` supporting the sorting of columns. By default it's sorted by computer, an arrow is indicating the sort order. I need this CSS style / arrow in another project, but even after examining the CSS code for this table header

```
<th class="name header headerSortDown">
    <a href="/computers?o=desc">Computer name</a>
</th>>
```

I still can't see where the arrow is coming from? Any hint on this? Thanks!

[image]

Update:

One can browse the CSS here: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/public/stylesheets

But on e.g. headerSortDown I can't find something that looks like an arrow ):

**For a follow up question:**

How to get the arrow directly next to the text?
[image]

Comment: It's in a CSS file, look for `.headerSortDown {...}`

Comment: I already had a look at this but couldn't find sth. that looks like an arrow. Added links to browse CSS, can you maybe check it? Thanks :-)

Comment: It's Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons. There's a sprite file somewhere, I assume it's not going to be a standalone file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use inspection tool of your browser (ie FireBug in Firefox or built-in inspector in Chrome)

Here's standalone extract of the arrows, as you can see they are 'drawing' the arrows with CSS border (no image required)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arrows a'la Twitter Bootstrap</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            .header {
                width: 200px;
                background-color: #c2ccd1;
                padding: 4px;
                margin: 2px;
            }

            .header:after {
                content: "";
                float: right;
                margin-top: 7px;
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .headerSortDown:after, .header:hover:after {
                border-width: 0 4px 4px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #000 transparent;
                visibility: visible;
            }

            .headerSortUp:after {
                border-bottom: none;
                border-left: 4px solid transparent;
                border-right: 4px solid transparent;
                border-top: 4px solid #000;
                visibility: visible;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">Not selected</div>
        <div class="header headerSortDown">Arrow up (sorting ASC)</div>
        <div class="header headerSortUp">Arrow down (sorting DESC)</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's [nice tutorial about drawing triangles with CSS border](http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/).

**Edit**

**DIV** tag  uses a `block` display so it tries to use full width OR the width given in CSS style (in above sample it's `200px`) if you'll use that arrow with some `inline` element like `A` or `SPAN` the arrow will be 'glued' to the text. Of course you can also force displaying DIV as an inline, the simplest way to do that (by modifying sample)

for `.header` declaration: remove `width` and add `display: inline-block;`:

```
.header {
    /* width: 200px; don't set width anymore */
    background-color: #c2ccd1;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block; /* force displaying DIV as an inline element */
}
```

To control space between text and arrow just use `margin-left` property for `.header:after` part:

```
.header:after {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left:4px; /* space between text and arrow for inline elements */
}
```

OR if you want to preserve a space for the arrow in the inline elements (to avoid width changes on hover) - you can also add transparent 'arrow'

```
.header:after {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    visibility: visible; /* make it visible by default */
    margin-left:4px; /* space between text and arrow for inline elements */
    border: 4px solid transparent; /* set borders to transparent, so they won't show */
}
```

Comment: oh, so I found it, but didn't understand it, when I saw it ;-) Thanks for the sample, that's great :-)

Comment: one follow up questions: how to get the arrows directly next (still on the right side) to the header next?

Comment: please see "For a follow up question:" in my original post. I don't want the arrow on the outer right side, but directly next to the text :-)